Как отключить кнопку YouTube-Shorts в мобильной версии Youtube?
Недавно задался вопросом, можно ли модифицировать интерфейс мобильных приложений.
Например, мне уже давно надоели YouTube-Shorts в мобильной версии. Если версию YouTube для ПК в браузере модифицировать несложно, то как быть с Android приложением? Иногда я захожу в ютуб и мне автоматически открываются YouTube-Shorts, это очень отвлекает. Спасибо

Используй нормальные (сторонние) приложения. Например для приставок/ТВ smarttube  супер.
